# $(window) bind hashchange how to check part hash changed?

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I am studing `Google Ajax Crawlable`

I use `$(window) bind hashchange` to control ajax page loading.

my url like:  `domain.com/#!/keywords&num=1`

there has two kind of change

1. `domain.com/#!/apple&num=1` => `domain.com/#!/apple&num=2`
2. `domain.com/#!/apple&num=1` => `domain.com/#!/banana&num=1`

so how to check if `$(window) bind hashchange` changed hash part from `apple` => `banana` ? Thanks.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    // make a judge like  if(){}else{}
});
```

Comment: The second updated hash did not only change fruit name, but also the number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Store the hash in a variable, and update the variable at the end of the function. Consider:

```
(function(){
    var lastHash = location.hash;
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        var newHash = location.hash;
        // Do something
        var diff = compareHash(newHash, lastHash);
        alert("Difference between old and new hash:\n"+diff[0]+"\n\n"+dif[1]);

        //At the end of the func:
        lastHash = newHash;
    });

    function compareHash(current, previous){
        for(var i=0, len=Math.min(current.length, previous.length); i<len; i++){
            if(current.charAt(0) != previous.charAt(0)) break;
        }
        current = current.substr(i);
        previous = previous.substr(i);
        for(var i=0, len=Math.min(current.length, previous.length); i<len; i++){
            if(current.substr(-1) != previous.substr(-1)) break;
        }

        //Array: Current = New hash, previous = old hash
        return [current, previous];
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would store the original hash in a variable, and then examine the new hash to judge the change. Once that is done, set the new hash to be the original:

```
var originalHash = window.location.hash;
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var newHash = window.location.hash;
    //do your stuff based on the comparison of newHash to originalHash

    originalHash = newHash;
});
```

Comment: can I detect change of (window.location) and handle it? (without jquery)