# How can I send a data to an iframe from main page when I working another iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a question about data transfer on iframes as can be seen in the picture below

http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/143/qcvf.jpg

My main page has 2 iframe. 
How can I send a data to textbox iframe_b from main page when I working  iframe_a?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `postMessage` would work.  You need control of the code of the other site. See TobSpr's link

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the iframe's src with a hash, and detect hashChange within the iframe. [$(window) bind hashchange how to check part hash changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699073/window-bind-hashchange-how-to-check-part-hash-changed)

If you want to set data into iframe in script directly, I remember, not so sure, if the src of iframe is a different host, you cannot, for security reason.