# jquery tabs have to click twice to show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabLink").each(function(){
        if(location.hash) {
            $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
            $(location.hash+"-1").addClass("activeLink");

            $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide")
            $(location.hash+"-1").removeClass("hide")
        } else {
                $(".tablink").click(function(){
                    $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
                    $(this).addClass("activeLink");

                    $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide")
                    $(location.hash+"-1").removeClass("hide")
                });
        }
    });
});
```

to switch between tabs, my html is:

```
<a href="#companyinfo" class="tabLink activeLink">Company</a> 
<a href="#contacts" class="tabLink">Contacts</a>
<div class="tabcontent" id="companyinfo-1"> 

</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="contacts-1"> 

</div>
```

when i choose another tab i have to click it twice to make the div show

here is a fiddle with the full code : http://jsfiddle.net/2SRZE/

Comment: Ps.: There is a typo on `$(".tablink").click(function(){`, You have lower case `L` on `.tablink`.

Comment: @user13500 well spotted but still nothing - http://jsfiddle.net/2SRZE/7/

Comment: @user3223205 Still interested in events based solely on `window.hash` change? See my new answer below…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2SRZE/10/)

Why not keep it simple and grab the target right off the anchor link instead of the page URL?

```
<div class="tab-box"> 
    <a href="#companyinfo-1" class="tabLink activeLink">Company</a> 
    <a href="#contacts-1" class="tabLink">Contacts</a>
</div>

<div class="tabcontent" id="companyinfo-1"> 
    Tab 1 Content    
</div>

<div class="tabcontent hide" id="contacts-1"> 
    Tab 2 Content    
</div>


   $(document).ready(function() {
       if(location.hash) {
         // maybe do a little more validation here
         setActiveLink(location.hash);
       }
       $('.tabLink').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr('href');
           document.location.hash = target;
           setActiveLink(target);

       });

       function setActiveLink(target) {
           $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
           $('a[href=' + target + ']').addClass("activeLink");
           $('.tabcontent').addClass('hide');
           $(target).removeClass('hide');
       }
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't keep the lat selected tab on page refresh which is why i was trying to use #contacts etc on the end of the url

Comment: still not keeping it selected

Comment: its not putting the # on the end of the url when i click a link/tab

Comment: check now.. removed `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: thats great - only thing is when i click one its making the page scroll because of the # - is it possible to stop this ?

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489624/modifying-document-location-hash-without-page-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

A comment on why you have to click twice:

When you click the *tab* and the event is triggered the address of the window still has not changed. On first click that would mean no hash. On subsequent clicks that would mean the hash has the value of *previous* clicked anchor.

1. Page enter: `hash == ''`
2. Click on *Contacts*: `hash == ''`
3. Hide content. (Company is being hided.)
4. Show `hash + '-1'` (no match as hash is empty.)
5. Event done, window hash changes: `hash == '#contacts'`
6. Click on `#contacts`: `hash == '#contacts'`
7. Hide content. (Nothing to hide).
8. Show `hash + '-1'`: `contacts-1` show.

Easier by example. Here the text-box is updated with hash value on each click.

<kbd>[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/2SRZE/8/)</kbd>

As you can see, the hash changes *too late*.

So: As noted by Lucky Soni, check the target event's `href` value.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/svP3T/2/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
       $($(".activeLink").attr('href') + '-1').removeClass("hide");
       $(".tabLink").each(function () {
           var _tabLink = $(this);
           var _tabLinkAttr = $(_tabLink.attr('href') + '-1');
           _tabLink.click(function () {
               $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
               _tabLink.addClass("activeLink");

               $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
               _tabLinkAttr.removeClass("hide");
           });
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/svP3T/4/

see this too: [$(window) bind hashchange how to check part hash changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699073/window-bind-hashchange-how-to-check-part-hash-changed)

```
var originalHash = window.location.hash;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        // remove all active
        $(".tabLink").removeClass("activeLink");
        $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699073/window-bind-hashchange-how-to-check-part-hash-changed
        var newHash = window.location.hash;
        var _origHash = originalHash;
        originalHash = newHash;

        // log
        console.log('original: ' + _origHash);
        console.log('new: ' + newHash);

        // update active
        $('[href="' + newHash + '"]').addClass("activeLink");
        $(newHash + '-1').removeClass("hide");
    });

    // init    
    $(".tabcontent").addClass("hide");
    $($(".activeLink").attr('href') + '-1').removeClass("hide");
});
```